# PHP exec() function returns status code 2

Tags: php

I had a problem while using PHP `exec()`. I am not able to figure out the issue and I have tried with following code:

```
exec("pdfcrop --margins '-6 -2 -3 -2' '/home/username/pdf/Figure 1 Timeline of Virtual Sim Use/page.01.pdf' '/home/username/pdf/out/output.pdf'", $output, $error);
```

Whenever I use this commands in `exec()` it returns status code of 2 but if I use this command to my terminal then it works well. So kindly give your suggestion to solve this problem.

thank you..

Comment: Maybe [**this**](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html) might help

Comment: Thanks for your response. Also i have tried with shell_exec() but same result not working.

Comment: `exec()` doesn't return status codes, it returns the last line from the result of the command. Do you mean that `$error` is 2? Do you mean [PDFCrop](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: yes it is an error code and i need to run pdfcrop with exec() function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

php exec function runs the process under the apache user ( www-data ) user most probably this user does not have access to :
/home/username/pdf/Figure

You can test this very easy by trying to change this path to /tmp/name of pdf file.pdf

Answer (score 0):

`pdfcrop` is a Perl program. Opening it to read, you will find it creates `tmp` files in current directory.
It works in PHP call after I made the following changes:

- $tmp = "/tmp/tmp-..."
- pdftex - add argument  -output-directory=/tmp

Answer (score 0):

In case of Linux Debian 9.5 I have got from Php `exec()` function return code 2 because wrong console for user www-data in `/etc/passwd` file:
I had to change line:

```
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

To:

```
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/bash
```

And now error gone and commands are executed as expected!